# Error setting up iCloud Documents with SwiftData

Tags: swift, swift-data

I'm trying to use an iCloud Documents folder inside my App that uses SwiftData. I've set up the entitlements, but the App crashes on startup.

The error happens here:

```
var sharedModelContainer: ModelContainer = {
    let schema = Schema([SomeModel.self])
    let modelConfiguration = ModelConfiguration(schema: schema, isStoredInMemoryOnly: false)

    do {
        return try ModelContainer(for: schema, configurations: [modelConfiguration])
    } catch {
        fatalError("Could not create ModelContainer: \(error)") // <- crash here
    }
}()
```

This is the error message: `Thread 1: Fatal error: Could not create ModelContainer: SwiftDataError(_error: SwiftData.SwiftDataError._Error.loadIssueModelContainer)`

I'm only using the iCloud Documents service, not CloudKit. The error is gone as soon as I uncheck iCloud Documents under Capabilities.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even though I wasn’t using CloudKit, following the [CloudKit requirements](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/swiftdata/how-to-sync-swiftdata-with-icloud) for swiftData seems to have fixed the issue:

- No `@Attribute(.unique)` on any property
- All properties must either have default values or be marked as optional, alongside their initializer.
- All relationships must be marked optional.

They show up as errors when ticking `CloudKit`. Otherwise it just crashed without any info.